# nan в результате действия

Tags: jquery

```js
var summ;
function selectItem(id) {
  summ += Number($('#item-' + id).attr('data-price'));
  $('#summ').text(summ);
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="block1">
  <div class="item-1" onclick="selectItem(1);" data-price="10" >selectItem(1)</div>
  <div class="item-2" onclick="selectItem(2);" data-price="20" >selectItem(2)</div>
</div>
<br>
summ: <div id="summ"></div>
```

Код должен считать сумму по атрибуту `data-price`, но почему-то отдает `NaN`

Comment: _undefined_ + любое число - даст _NaN_

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. задайте начальное значение для `summ`
2. ищите класс `.item-`, а не идентификатор `#item-`

```js
var summ = 0;
function selectItem(id) {
  summ += Number( $('.item-' + id).data('price') );
  $('#summ').text(summ);
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="block1">
  <div class="item-1" onclick="selectItem(1);" data-price="10" >selectItem(1)</div>
  <div class="item-2" onclick="selectItem(2);" data-price="20" >selectItem(2)</div>
</div>
<br>
summ: <div id="summ"></div>
```

Answer (score 2):

В данном случае не инициализирована переменная *summ*. Ее значение по умолчанию - *undefined*.

Результат сложения *undefined* с любым числом даст *NaN*.

Как верно заметил [@GlebKemarsky](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/661185/186999) разметке присутствуют элементы с *классом*, а в функции ищутся элементы с *id*. Из-за этого,

```
$('#item-' + id).data('price')
```

Вернет *undefined*, и `Number(undefined)` даст `NaN`.